# jQuery checkbox does not trigger event after Select All method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox, jquery-events

I have a table with some jQuery checkboxes.  As each checkbox is clicked, this triggers a method to update a total in the bottom row using: `onclick="UpdateTotalFee()"`

When the page initially loads, everything works perfectly as expected.  Each checkbox click fires the `UpdateTotalFee()` method.

Where the problem arises is after a user clicks the select all link.  This operates to select all of the checkboxes correctly, however, subsequent clicks on the checkboxes no longer trigger the method to update the total.

When I inspect in firebug, one difference that I can see is that when the page first loads, clicks on the checkboxes seem to be clicking on the `span.checkboxplaceholder`, but after clicking the select all link, subsequent clicks on the checkboxes do not seem to invoke the same thing.

I hope I've explained the situation well enough.  Here is the complete code for the table:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th style="vertical-align:middle;">Number</th>
    <th style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle;">Owner</th>
    <th style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle;">Address</th>
    <th style="vertical-align:middle;">Code</th>
    <th style="vertical-align:middle;">Class</th>
    <th style="vertical-align:middle;">Filing Fee</th>
    <th style="text-align:center; width:75px;">Review ?<br />
    <a href="" onclick="select_all_com(); return false"><strong>All</strong></a>
     &nbsp;&nbsp;or&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="" onclick="select_none_com(); return false"><strong>None</strong></a>
    </th>
</tr>

<?php foreach ($property['commercial'] as $key => $value): ?>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo str_pad($row++, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); ?></th>
        <td><a href= "<?php echo site_url() . "propertydetail/viewpropertydetail/" . $value['property#']; ?>"><?php echo RollNumber($value['property#']); ?></a></td>
        <td style="text-align:left"><?php echo $value['Property Owner']; ?> </td>
        <td style="text-align:left"><?php echo $value['Property Address']; ?></td>
        <td style="text-align:middle" ><?php echo number_format($value['PC'],0); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['Class']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo money_format('$%.0i', 140); ?></td>
        <td id="com" style="padding-left:25px;" onclick="UpdateTotalFee()">
<input type="checkbox" name="file_com_appeal" class="com-checkbox" value="<?php echo $value['property#'] ?>"></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
    <th colspan="6" style="text-align:right; padding:1% 1% 1% 0%;">       
    <h4>TOTAL</h4><h5><span id="AppealSelected"></span></h5></th>
    <th ><h4><span id="AppealFeeTotal"></span></h4></th>
    <th></th>
```

Here is the Javascript function that is supposed to be called with each click of the checkbox:

```
function UpdateTotalFee(){
        var AppealCount = 0;
        $('input[name=file_com_appeal]').each(function(){
            if($(this).attr('checked')){
               AppealCount++;
            }
        });
        $('#AppealSelected').text(                                      
        (AppealCount == 0 ? '' : '(' + AppealCount + ' of ' + <?php echo count($property['commercial']);?> + (AppealCount == 1 ? ' property selected)' : ' properties selected)')));    
        $('#AppealFeeTotal').text("$"+(AppealCount*140));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please create one new function and call that function onclick of select All and pass the  total row count as a parameter of this function so you can calculate easily the total amount.

like `totalamount= count*140` 
and set this value using below code

```
$('#AppealFeeTotal').text("$"+(totalamount));
```

Answer (score 1):

checkboxes trigger "`onchange`" event if it is (un)checked.so rather listen for this event in your javascript code. And then check the whether the checkbox is checked in your event handler to apply changes to the total amount.
Sample:

```
[HTML]
<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" value="1" onchange="updateAmount();"/>

[JS]
function updateAmount(){
     if($('input#check').is(':checked')){
           // checked
     }else{
          // unchecked
     }
}
```